# How to Call a stored procedure from another stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have an insert stored procedure which takes many parameters - 2 of them are @FirstName, @LastName.
I also have an update stored procedure which takes many parameters - 2 of them are @FirstName, @LastName.

What I want to do is, from inside the insert SP, when it's done, call the update SP and send to it the @FirstName, @LastName.

I don't know the right syntax to do that; I tried:

```
exec  LandData_Update @FirstName, @LastName
```

But I think it's wrong.

Can someone tell me how to write this calling?

And if I will call the update sp with different param names? Such as @MyFirstName, @MyLastName? Would I write it like this: `EXECUTE LandData_Update @MyFirstName=@FirstName, @MyLastName=@LastName`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What makes you think it's wrong?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyInsertSP
    @FirstName varchar(255),
    @LastName  varchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table VALUES('Some Value')

    EXECUTE LandData_Update @FirstName, @LastName
END
```

Do you get an error or something?

**EDIT:**
It doesn't matter what the name of the variables are, but to do what you want you can declare two new variables.

```
DECLARE @MyFirstName varchar(255)
DECLARE @MyLastName  varchar(255)

SET @MyFirstName = @FirstName
SET @MyLastName  = @LastName
```

And then use the new variables. But again, the Store Procedure doesn't care what the variables are called.

Comment: and if i will call the update sp with different param names? such as @MyFirstName, @MyLastName? will write it like that: EXECUTE LandData_Update @MyFirstName=@FirstName, @MyLastName=@LastName   ??

Comment: Yes, that should work fine
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332(SQL.90).aspx