# Forcing the order that datasets get resolved?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I have 3 datasources and associated repeaters on the one .net page:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsMain" runat="server" 
    SelectCommand="mySP1" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsHeader" runat="server" 
    SelectCommand="mySP2" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsFooter" runat="server" 
    SelectCommand="mySP3" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">


<asp:Repeater ID="rptHeader" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsHeader" >
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMain" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsMain" >
<asp:Repeater ID="rptFooter" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsFooter" >
```

The datasource stored procedures are executed in the order that they are needed as the page is loaded (ie, `mySP2,mySP1,mySP3`). Is there any way I can force the order? The `dsMain` stored proc has side effects that change the results of the other two, and therefore needs to be executed first.

Currently I have added an empty dummy repeater at the beginning bound to dsMain to force it to be evaluated first, but this involves an extra round trip to the DB that I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Write one stored proc (called '`myMasterSP`' for example) that calls (`exec`'s) the other 3 in the order you required. You should not rely on the order that controls appear in the HTML mark up. Having a master stored proc means you only need to make the one call with on ASP.NET control.

Following link discusses stored proc's executing other stored procs:

[how to call a stored proc from another stored proc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184325/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-from-another-stored-procedure)