# Is it possible use spring data jpa with spring data jdbc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc, spring-data-jdbc

sorry for my noob question...

I'd like to know if it's possible to use spring data jdbc with spring data jpa...
If yes, how should configuration be set?

I'm working on a project which uses spring data jpa, and I need to call a procedure which uses a temporary table filled in memory...I don't know do it with spring data jpa and I'm thinking in doing this with jdbc...

I need do this steps in spring data jpa or jdbc:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp_parcela ( 
        Num_Parcela                   tinyint         NOT NULL, 
        Vlr_Emitido_Parcela           numeric(15,2)   NOT NULL, 
        Vlr_Emitido_Juros_Parcela     numeric(15,2)   NULL, 
        Vlr_Emitido_Cor_Mon_Parcela   numeric(15,2)   NULL, 
        Vlr_Emitido_Multa_Parcela     numeric(15,2)   NULL, 
        Dta_Vencto_Parc               datetime        NOT NULL
    ) 
    
    INSERT INTO #tmp_parcela VALUES (2, 125.52, 0, 0, 0, '2020-12-10 00:00:00')
    INSERT INTO #tmp_parcela VALUES (3, 125.52  , 0, 0, 0, '2020-12-10 00:00:00')  
    
    EXEC uspGTMGerar_DAM_ISS_Fixo @psUsuario = 'Curitiba App', @psMaquina = 'Curitiba App', @piNum_Inscricao_Debito_Origem = 48538554, @psiSeq_Debito_Origem = 0, @pdDta_Vencimento = '2020-12-10 00:00:00'

    DELETE #tmp_parcela
```

Comment: Did you try to wrap these queries into a stored procedure?  Which DB server do you use?

Comment: I'm using sybase with jtds

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Spring Data JPA and Spring Data JDBC together. Spring Boot will do the configuration for you, you just have to make sure that all entities handled by Spring Data JDBC have a `@Table` annotation.

But that is not what you want.

What you want is Spring JDBC (no DATA in there). It is part of the Spring Framework itself and especially you want the `JdbcTemplate`. Again Boot should basically do all the configuration when you include the Spring Boot Starter JDBC.

Just inject a `JdbcTemplate` where ever you need it and code away.
One option would be in a [custom method in your Spring Data JPA repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations).

How to use that is a completely separate question and you should open such a question if you don't already know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to call stored procedures from JPA repositories:

1. Use `@Procedure` annotation [JPA Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.stored-procedures)

```java
public MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
    @Procedure(procedureName = "mySP")
    int callMyStoredProcedure(String procParam);
}
```

2. Use `@Query` annotation as native query:

```java
@Query(value = "CALL FIND_MY_ENTITY(:proc_param);", nativeQuery = true)
List<MyEntity> findEntitesByParam(@Param("proc_param") String procParam);
```

Comment: Alex, the procedure I need to call needs a pre filled temporary table, I updated the question with details

Comment: You can create another stored procedure as a wrapper to prepare the temporary table (and pass relevant parameters inside if needed), and then execute the initial SP, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184325/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-from-another-stored-procedure

Comment: Alex, I can't do it...unhapilly I need to call this procedure as it is...do you know how do I configure spring jdbc and apring jpa togeter?

Comment: _Why_ cannot you do this as I described?  You need to make a single call anyway within the same transaction, otherwise you are likely to get into trouble when the temporary table already exists or when its data already updated by  another call to `uspGTMGerar_DAM_ISS_Fixo`.

Comment: How can I handle a temporary table in Spring Data JPA? I need to create it and delete it after calling stored procedure...

Comment: Not sure this is possible with JPA repositories as they are bound to entities mapped to common DB tables.

Comment: I dont have access to create a stored procedure at work...I need to use jdbc with spring data jpa...do you know how to config it?

Comment: I think you should discuss this question with your peers / senior dev / team lead.