# Can we use Spring Data JPA and JDBC together in same Spring Boot project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

I have 1 table `FEE` and created a `FeeRepository` for database operations on this table.

Also, I need some data from another table 'PAYMENTS'.

'FEE' and 'PAYMENTS' are in the same DB schema.

I plan to query PAYMENTS table using JDBC now.

**Intention is for better code readability.**

> Fee Queries will be at FeeRepository.java

> Payments Query will be at PaymentsDao.java

Would it be a good decision to use Spring JPA and JDBC together in same project ?

Comment: You can definitely make it work. Especially when splitting it up. If its a good decision to do so, depends on what exactly you need to do and why you need JDBC for that

Comment: Please check with that response- https://stackoverflow.com/a/64681823/19672116